# Segmentation fault on using std::string inside a dynamically allocated struct

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, struct

I was trying out a simple program to understand how to use a pointer to an array of pointers to structure.

I wrote this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A
{
   char* a1;
};

void fn1(A **d, int n)
{
    printf("5 \n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("val: %s \n",d[i]->a1);
    }
    printf("6 \n");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("0 \n");
    A *a,*b,*c;
    printf("1 \n");
    a = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    b = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    c = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    printf("2 \n");
    a->a1 = "hi";
    b->a1 = "bye";
    c->a1 = "see you";
    printf("3 \n");
    A *d[] = {a,b,c};
    printf("4 \n");
    fn1(d,3);
    printf("7 \n");
    printf("Program successfully completed \n");
}
```

The program compiled and executed properly and I got this output:

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
val: hi 
val: bye 
val: see you 
6 
7 
Program successfully completed
```

But while compiling I was getting these warnings on `deprecated conversion from string to char*` so I decided to change the `char*` in my struct to `std::string`. I changed the program into:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A
{
   std::string a1;
};

void fn1(A **d, int n)
{
    printf("5 \n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("val: %s \n",d[i]->a1.c_str());
    }
    printf("6 \n");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("0 \n");
    A *a,*b,*c;
    printf("1 \n");
    a = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    b = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    c = (A*)malloc(sizeof (A));
    printf("2 \n");
    a->a1 = "hi";
    b->a1 = "bye";
    c->a1 = "see you";
    printf("3 \n");
    A *d[] = {a,b,c};
    printf("4 \n");
    fn1(d,3);
    printf("7 \n");
    printf("Program successfully completed \n");
}
```

Now The program compiled properly but I got a `segmentation fault(core dumped)` on running. Not even the first `printf("0");` got displayed. Can anyone explain me what mistake am I doing here?

Comment: `malloc` and objects that need to be constructed don't get along very well.  Use `new`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja if that is the case why did not the first printf get printed? the code execution should have been normal till it executes the malloc line right?

Comment: To fix the warning in your first program: in the definition of `struct A`, change to `char const *a1;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb yeah I can do that but I just said what I tried and how I got to this error

Comment: Regarding the printf lines appearing: output is buffered in C++, so your program might crash before the buffered lines make it to your screen. Add `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf`.

Comment: Output through `printf` is generally buffered.  Perhaps the crash happened before the buffer was flushed.

Comment: yeah fflush prints it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` is not suitable for creating non-POD objects. It allocates memory but does not call any constructors. So your line `a->a1` accesses a string that has not yet been constructed, causing undefined behaviour.

To properly allocate and construct the object use:

```
a = new A;
```

It is bad style (at best) to use `malloc` in any C++ program

Comment: if mallocing is the problem why doesn't the first printf get printed?

Comment: Output is buffered in C++, so your program might crash before the buffered lines make it to your screen. Add `fflush(stdout);` after each printf.